# property of User model from http request returns null

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to make a login request to my backend and display the authenticated user name on my dashboard screen. I did a print statement to try and access one of the properties and I get null. This is the response I get from my backend

```
{success: {token: nC2vgm8WJgcLVx0Jpppb1JghR6b8iUnBbWNrSmOH7znjYt06d_, user: {firstName: John, lastName: Doe, phoneNumber: 01234567}
```

My User model is like this;

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class AuthUser extends Equatable {

 final String firstName;
 final String lastName;
 final String phoneNumber;

  AuthUser({
      @required this.firstName,
      @required this.lastName,
      @required this.phoneNumber,
  });


factory AuthUser.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return AuthUser(
      firstName: json['firstName'],
      lastName: json['lastName'],
      phoneNumber: json['phoneNumber'],
    );
 }

 @override
 List<Object> get props => [firstName, lastName, email];
}
```

This is my authRepository

```
import 'package:flutter_repo/models/auth-user.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';


abstract class AuthRepository {

    Future<AuthUser> doLogin(data);
}


class Auth implements AuthRepository {

   final baseUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/v1";

  @override
  Future<AuthUser> doLogin(data) async {
     final response = await http.post('$baseUrl/user/login', body: data);

     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          var user =  AuthUser.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)); 
          print(user.firstName);
          return user;
    }else {
       throw new Exception('Failed To Login User');
    }
 }
}
```

Printing user.firstName gives me null. Here is what my json response gives me

```
{success: {token: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiMmJjNWM1ZDk1NGU2ZDY4ZTg5MTEzMThkMGY0Yjc3OGNlNDJhNDNiNThlODJkMWQ3ZTUxMmMzOTQ0MzFlOTJkNjRiMjMxYzczOTVmZDEyYWUiLCJpYXQiOjE1ODEwODIxNzAsIm5iZiI6MTU4MTA4MjE3MCwiZXhwIjoxNjEyNzA0NTcwLCJzdWIiOiIyIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.Lnu09KKeL9LdJbKKPega3xIa4c4j_T00rY3pIvp3-b6mi3PRf1oKmw0kaITenmEcPdyjLHiOZWxTXycTQwx1IOKGMf86HS2K8rmuPna9hxoMHOjJWgsw0Rorn0YTkHdGZZJ8uCtbIK3jss0nRjHgLYkvtwZ0jHC8b8qfSf1bcj2nGYLRNboMMo2GuIdBybJdmLM_Z7Z6CiRS2j9QuVhT_oS62QhWSR07jF3NsjCmH8RoUCS0goOan2hkSl3lava7tAoodH_JrxHo86Fk3i8N4Idt3-P-Q3OsWl2t67HizZ7i_87TcYP3RtwSpKMKkllBLiWoXWZriqhv0wdwmxwfAySyKqCEDei9pCFEz-nQYOxmldTMq-UXOZlFjy4Mcx_o-It8CbrHaCcyESV-iAjdoamdjQtujKOGP-GngM7jBgCxjsnavgeYzPLRF9_yTzSdI7CUWQFoK_Ja2DM3WswOGG4kdCp3K7uifklO69pVo1INQQN7Uf6oVI4XfAzeEQGLqW9eX8reFx7SzZglQGePDn1zonWNmUgZ19k5MbRRlH2mwt1pP-dt8L9t07cLdjKqHj68HtmE2tcP0U4Lv1ApT_v0erskolNL6bD3y_dE7re74UQtl5FrGZciDWiYkt1v1BecsIAWumM8eKoWAKgURcgdydIWr8q4GzkRp_BKyXs, user: {firstName: Patrick, lastName: Obafemi, phoneNumber} }
```

How can I retrieve the values of my user model correctly

Comment: Can you show us a `print` of the `user` variable once you get the response from `AuthUser.fromJson(json.decode(response.body))`?

Comment: printing user variable returns the json string of my backend response.

Comment: If it's just json and not a `Map` then you can't use `user.firstName`. You would have to use `user['firstName']`.

Comment: Oh that's true. So i have to convert the response to a map, right?

Comment: Check my response for a User model approach to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would have a User class made by you where you could write a `.toJson` method to help you parse the data coming in, like this for example:

```
class User {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  int phoneNumber;

  ...

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this.firstName = json['firstName'];
    this.lastName = json['lastName'];
    this.phoneNumber = json['phoneNumber'];
  }
}
```

---

According to the json structure you shared, this should work:

```
var response = AuthUser.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)); 

User user = User.fromJson(
  jsonResponse['success']['user']
);
```

Comment: From my response how can i just get the users object? Right now it is returning a success object with a token string and a users object.

Comment: Can you share the actual json response?

Comment: @PatrickObafemi I've added to my response what I expect would work with your json structure, where `user` is inside `success`. I also updated the field names to match yours.

Answer (score 1):

You have to encode only the user. You can try this:

```
var user =  AuthUser.fromJson(json.decode(response.body['success']['user']));
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I get an error though. It says The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.

Comment: @PatrickObafemi replace `phoneNumber: json['phoneNumber']` with `phoneNumber: json['phoneNumber'].toString()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

Create an Instance of AuthUser,

```
Future<AuthUser> auser;

   //Assign response to it;

auser = AuthUser.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
```

Now you can print

```
print(post.username);
```

For more detail  check out this [example](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/authenticated-requests) or this [one](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data)

Comment: Well I still get the error The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'AuthUser'.
Try defining the operator '[]'

Comment: i think you need to take a look at this example https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data